# How can i view a already typed password from a mozilla window class?

Tags: passwords, encryption, firefox

With the help of password viewer s/w am able to view the passwords from only the msngr type boxes .So how can i view a already typed pswd from mozilla class window type??

Comment: Are you trying to view a 'saved' password? If so goto options - security - saved password and there is an option to show passwords.

Comment: MrStatic am not trying to view a saved password by me. any way i got a trick i can answer myself itseems.

Answer (score 1):

We can make a bookmarklet link in Mozilla so that we can view the password simply.

Go to Bookmarks -> Organize Bookmarks -> double click the bookmarks menu -> right click -> new bookmark-> give any name (eg:pswd reveal) -> in the loacation field just paste this script:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20s,F,j,f,i;%20s%20=%20%22%22;%20F%20=%20document.forms;%20for(j=0;%20j<F.length;%20++j)%20{%20f%20=%20F[j];%20for%20(i=0;%20i<f.length;%20++i)%20{%20if%20(f[i].type.toLowerCase()%20==%20%22password%22)%20s%20+=%20f[i].value%20+%20%22\n%22;%20}%20}%20if%20(s)%20alert(%22Passwords%20in%20forms%20on%20this%20page:\n\n%22%20+%20s);%20else%20alert(%22There%20are%20no%20passwords%20in%20forms%20on%20this%20page.%22);})();
```

-> add

That's all.  By going to Bookmarks and selecting the new *"pswd reveal"* bookmark it will run this script.

Comment: aren't you missing at least few closing brackets

Comment: @bbaja42: it wasn't missing, just didn't display because Markdown ate it.  edited to put it in a code sample, so it should display completely now.